# Laravel Auth::attempt return Undefined array key 1

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, laravel-9

i have an error in my laravel project but i dont know where the error, when i,m trying to login its return Undefined array key 1.
[Here is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA3o1.png)

here is my code.

This is my Login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie as FacadesCookie;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function authenticate(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required | min:5 | max:50'
        ]);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            if($request->has('remember')){
                FacadesCookie::queue('adminuser', $request->username,1440);
                FacadesCookie::queue('adminpw', $request->password,1440);
            }
            
            return redirect()->intended('/beranda_admin');
        }

        return back()->with('loginError', 'Login Gagal!');

    }
}
```

this is the Login Blade

```
<div class="container">
        @if(session()->has('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
                {{ session('success') }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        @endif

        @if(session()->has('loginError'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
                {{ session('loginError') }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="forms-container">
            <img src="img/login.png" alt="icon back" class="img">
       
            <div class="login">
                <!-- form login -->
                <form action="{{ url('/login') }}" method="POST" class="login">
                    @csrf
                    <h2 class="title">LPPM SINGLE SIGN ON</h2>
                    <!-- username login -->
                    <h3>Username</h3>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" name="username" @if(Cookie::has('adminuser')) value="{{ Cookie::get('adminuser') }}" @endif
                        id="username" autofocus required value="{{ old('username') }}">
                    </div>
                    <!-- password login -->
                    <h3>Password</h3>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="password" name="password"  @if(Cookie::has('adminpw')) value="{{ Cookie::get('adminpw') }}" @endif id="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- remember me-->
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" @if(Cookie::has('adminuser')) checked @endif name="remember" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                        <label>
                            Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn solid">
                </form>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'beranda']);
Route::get('/beranda_admin', [PagesController::class, 'beranda_admin'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/hlmnlogin', [PagesController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('/form_izinpenelitian', [PagesController::class, 'form_izin_penelitian']);
Route::get('/form_izinpengabdian', [PagesController::class, 'form_izin_pengabdian']);
Route::get('/form_tugaspenelitian', [PagesController::class, 'form_tugas_penelitian']);
Route::get('/form_tugaspengabdian', [PagesController::class, 'form_tugas_pengabdian']);
Route::post('/izinpenelitian', [PagesController::class, 'store_permohonan']);
Route::post('/izinpengabdian', [PagesController::class, 'store_permohonan']);
Route::post('/tugaspenelitian', [PagesController::class, 'store_tugas']);
Route::post('/tugaspengabdian', [PagesController::class, 'store_tugas']);
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);
Route::get('/ganti_password', [LoginController::class, 'gantiPassword']);
Route::post('/ganti_password', [LoginController::class, 'updatePassword']);
```

i dont know where the error, but it happen after i try to add captcha feature and fail. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: `$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');` do this after validating the request and before `Auth::attempt($credentials)`. Can you let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, it is still show the same error, and the resulting query is like this: select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1